# Two Datagrids have the same source, but output slightly different results

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have a view with a `DataGrid`. This `DataGrid`, is bound to a `List` in my ViewModel.
And my ViewModel populates this List by use of EF6 and MySQL 5.6. It retrieves its data from a view rather than a table.

The wierd thing is: when my application displays the data, there's a row that 'seems' to be duplicated over another.
However, in Mysql Workbench, this same row is not duplicated at all. Take a look below:

[image: Workbench showing view]

Above is the datagrid from Workbench showing details as they are.
But...

[image: datagrid from my App hallucinating]

In my app the same row seems to be duplicated.

Ironically - in my app - should I specify the `Format` field to only show 'RTGS' payments, the same 'duplicate' row will feature in the results. Despite rendering 'Cash' in the `Format` field.

The code to populate this Datagrid:

xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ContributionsList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

ViewModel

```
var ContributionsQuery = ((LogicApp)Application.Current).ContextHeavy.viewcontributionsjournals.Where(
                        t => t.Captured > MinRequestedDate
                        && t.Captured < MaxRequestedDate);

                    ContributionsList = new List<viewcontributionsjournal>(ContributionsQuery);
```

Any idea what's causing this behaviour? Aside from the first few columns, these rows should share nothing in common. So why does it seem like one is overwriting the other?

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you specify DistinctBy() based on receipt number? i.e.:

```
var ContributionsQuery = (((LogicApp)Application.Current).ContextHeavy.viewcontributionsjournals.Where(
                        t => t.Captured > MinRequestedDate
                        && t.Captured < MaxRequestedDate)).DistinctBy(a => a.ReceiptNo);
```

Does it still 'overwrite' that one record?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I only ever have Internet art work. This solution did remove one of the rows. But it wasn't the overwritten one though. Turns out changin my view from left join to inner join did the trick though.